# javascript string replace ( with \(

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

How can I transform the string "Test(5)" into "Test\(5\)" dynamically? (JQuery or Javascript)

I have tried this but with no success

```
var string = "Test(5)";

string = string.replace("(","\(");
string = string.replace(")","\)");

console.log(string);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mvehkkfe/

Comment: replace the string "Test(5)" into "Test(5)" ??? what does it mean?

Comment: What's the issue here? Why replace Test(5) with Test(5)？

Comment: The backslashes weren't properly escaped. I fixed that so it should be clearer now

Comment: str = 'Test(5)'.replace(/(\w)\((\d)\)/gi, "$1\\($2\\)");
alert(str2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant

> replace the string "Test(5)" into "Test\(5\)"

In which case:

```
var string = "Test(5)";

string = string.replace("(","\\(");
string = string.replace(")","\\)");

console.log(string);
```

Escape the backslash

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace the string "Test(5)" into "Test\(5\)", you can use below code

```
var string = "Test(5)";

string = string.replace("(","\\(");
string = string.replace(")","\\)");

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is this the same as my answer that was posted earlier?